# WWF service and ASP.NET client on the same server

Tags: workflow-foundation

Is there anything wrong with having my WWF service inside the same project with the ASP.NET client that consumes it? Currently the ASP.NET client is the only client but more may be added later. Do you think that the overhead of calling the service using SOAP is significant (because they are on the same server, so it could call it directly).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this.  If you are concerned about the overhead you can call the service using the NetNamedPipeBinding provided you have enabled the protocol on the Web Application.  Simply replace the http:// scheme with net.pipe://.  The communication layer will be much faster using net.pipe but even so the communication overhead in such scenarios is typically a very small amount so don't expect to see enormous performance gains from this kind of change.